# How to copy file from a form into my root web app Java EE

Tags: java, forms

I have a productForm as follows :

```
<form id="addProduct" method="post" action="createProduct" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="text" name="productName">
    <input type="file" name="productImage">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Here is my (almost) empty Action :

```
@Action("/createProduct")
@ResultPath("/")
@Result(location = "jsp/board.jsp")
public class CreateAction extends ActionSupport {

    private Integer id;

    @Autowired
    private UserDao userDao;
    @Autowired
    private Product product;
    @Autowired
    private Supplier supplier;

    private List<Product> products;

    public String execute() {


        return "success";
    }
```

I'd like to copy the file entered in the root of my application. How can i do that in my Action ?

Ideally, i'd also like to store filename & URL in variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to create the `getter` and `setter` for the fields `productName` and `productImage` in your action class and add the `@Action` on `execute` method:

```
   public class CreateAction extends ActionSupport {

   private File productImage;
   private String myFileContentType;
   private String myFileFileName;
   private String destPath;

   @Action("/createProduct")
   public String execute() {

  destPath = "destination file folder";

  try{

     File destFile  = new File(destPath, myFileFileName);
     FileUtils.copyFile(productImage, destFile);

     }catch(IOException e){
     e.printStackTrace();
      }
    return "success";
   } 
   public File getProductImage() {
      return productImage;
    }
     public void setProductImage(File productImage) {
       this.productImage= productImage;
       }
      public String getMyFileContentType() {
      return myFileContentType;
     }
   public void setMyFileContentType(String myFileContentType) {
      this.myFileContentType = myFileContentType;
     }
    public String getMyFileFileName() {
       return myFileFileName;
      }
    public void setMyFileFileName(String myFileFileName) {
       this.myFileFileName = myFileFileName;
      }

   }
```

In form try to use post method.

Comment: Hello @Abdelhak i'm wondering how is that copying the file to my root folder ?